# Gradle installed via snap on Raspberry Pi cannot build, missing cacerts

Tags: java, gradle, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B set up headless with the latest Raspberry Pi OS. I installed git and pulled a Java/Kotlin project that I intend to build on the Pi. I installed `Gradle` via snap: `sudo snap install gradle --classic`. Current Gradle version is 6.8.3

Trying to build, Gradle now fails to download dependencies, apparently due to missing cacerts. This is the stacktrace (shortened, since it was too long for a question):

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4.32/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.32.pom'.
            > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: /snap/gradle/80/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'experiment'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)

Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: /snap/gradle/80/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2049)

    ... 214 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: /snap/gradle/80/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)

    ... 247 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /snap/gradle/80/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.DefaultSslContextFactory$SslContextCacheLoader.initTrustManagerFactory(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.DefaultSslContextFactory$SslContextCacheLoader.load(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:119)
    ... 256 more
```

I understand that there seem to be missing certificates, but it is unclear to me how I can resolve this in a clean way. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm suddenly running into the same issue on Fedora.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for this yet. My workaround, since I wanted to build a jar to be used in a docker image, was to move the build process into docker too, and  circumvent the issue that way.